SvelteKitError: Not found: /index.js - How can I fix this?
SvelteKitError: Not found: /index.js
    at resolve (<project_dir>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:525:13)
    at resolve (<project_dir>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:325:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (<project_dir>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:71:56)
    at Module.respond (<project_dir>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:322:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}

Does anyone know why this error occurs?
This error shows up unexpectedly. Despite the error being present, the SvelteKit app works fine including hot-reload. Just wanted to know what causes it.

Show a minimal reproduction, including the relevant config/package files.
